# Format numbers with apostrophe as thousands separator

Tags: javascript, regex

I have number from API provided in this way 774317 and I have to convert it to this value 774'317.00, so if there are 2 more decimals they should be separated with full stop like this

```
77431745 => 774'317.45
```

Following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/3918577 I make it to separate thousands (so It format it to this 774'317), but last 2 decimals are issue for me, because I'm not very good with RegEX.Below is code that I used for this

```
convertMonetary(value) {
  return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "'")
}
```

Comment: which country format is it?

Comment: Will there be other inputs, like `3344.34`? Or `33.3`?

Comment: Use [Number.prototype.toFixed(2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) before executing the regex to handle the number of decimals.

Comment: @NinaScholz It should be Switzerland (CHF)

Comment: Nope @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @Aaron toFixed will convert it to 77431745.000

Comment: @S.Petrosov toFixed accepts a number of digits as parameter, so it should convert 774317 to 774317.00, from where we apply the regex to obtain 774'317.00 ; this is following the text of the first paragraph, which I agree is in contrast to the example just below

Comment: @Aaron he needs to do this 33333333 ->333'333.33 but toFixed(2) will return 33333333.00

Comment: @S.Petrosov well then divide by 100 _before_ applying toFixed ...

Comment: @CBroe yeah divide will do exactly what he needs

Comment: @CBroe have to divide value with 1, with 100, it set separator on wrong place.

Comment: See `console.log((Number("1234567")/100).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1'"));`. And a catch: it will only work with whole numbers, or numbers with 1 or 2 digits in the fractional part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very explicit in exactly *when* the last two digits are **not** decimals and `.00` needs to be added, and *when* the last two digits **are** decimals and only a `.` needs to be added in the right place.

The code below assumes that with **6** or fewer digits, the `.00` need to be added, otherwise the last 2 digits are seen as decimals and a `.` is added.

When you run it, the first 2 rows are your example data, the lower 2 rows are examples where I added a `1` before the number to demonstrate how numbers of those lengths get treated.

```js
function convertMonetary(inp) {
  return inp.replace(/^(\d*?\d{1,6})(\d{2})?$/, function(m, whole, dec) {
    return whole.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "'") + ((dec!=undefined)?'.'+dec:'.00');
  });
}

document.getElementById('outp').value = 
  '77431745  => ' + convertMonetary('77431745') + '\n' +
  '774317    => ' + convertMonetary('774317') + '\n\n' +
  '177431745 => ' + convertMonetary('177431745') + '\n' +
  '1774317   => ' + convertMonetary('1774317')
```

```html
<textarea id="outp" rows="10" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

To explain a bit why the regex is the way it is:

`(\d*?\d{1,6})` might make little sense on first sight, why not just do `\d+`. The thing is that the `{1,6}` quantifier of the latter `\d` is greedy, the first `\d`'s quantifier `*?` is not, this makes that `(\d{2})?` only gets matched when there are more than 6 digits in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Use **toLocaleString()** with Swiss country code (**de-CH**), here's a sample utility:

```js
export const formatNumber = (x, places = 2, country = 'de-CH') => {
  return Number(x || 0).toLocaleString(country, {
    maximumFractionDigits: places,
    minimumFractionDigits: places,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to suggestion by @Aaron, problem is fixed.

I used the toFixed() before RegEx execution, and divided value by 1, code is below.

```
convertMonetary(value) {
    let val = (value/1).toFixed(2)
    return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "'")
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does that mean you just need `"1234567"` -> `1'234'567.00`? You could use your regex and then append `.00` then.

Comment: You are right, just tested the 77431745 and it return it like this 77'431'745.00 this, which is not correct.
Any idea ? If I divide value with 100 it would work for this, but then another numbers won't be correct.

Comment: And what is correct output for that `"1234567"` value? What other numbers? Please provide the comprehensive set of test cases in the question.

Comment: 12'345.67 @WiktorStribiżew